# Shifting by random index in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arraylistexample {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Enter how many values you want to enter");
        Scanner scr =new Scanner(System.in);
        int s=scr.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the values");
        for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            String sr=sc.nextLine();
            al.add(sr);
        }
        al.add(2, "Tom");
        al.add(1, "Henry");
        al.add(0, "Natalie");
        System.out.println("The values you entered are:");
        for(String str:al)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }
    }
```

In the above code I am trying to take values from the user and trying to store it in a ArrayList. After the user enters the values, the program again enters some more values at specified index by shifting the original values. When I  execute the program by entering the values sequentially it gives me no error. But whenever I try to do it in the above process it gives me error as

```
Enter how many values you want to enter

2

Enter the values

Harry

Potter

The values you entered are:

Natalie

Harry

Henry

Potter

Tom
```

Whereas the output should be

```
Natalie 

Henry 

Tom 

Harry 

Potter
```

I still cant figure out why the shifting is not done though if values are entered in a random manner.

Comment: Why are you creating multiple `Scanner` objects?

Comment: the output is correct, `0=Harry, 1=Potter`, after inserting `Tom` at 2, we get `0=Harry, 1=Potter, 2=Tom`; after inserting `Henry` at 1, we get `0=Harry, 1=Henry, 2=Potter, 3=Tom`; after inserting `Natalie` at 0, we get `0=Natalie, 1=Harry, 2=Henry, 3=Potter, 3=Tom`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are adding

```
    al.add(2, "Tom");
    al.add(1, "Henry");
    al.add(0, "Natalie");
```

Adding `Tom` at `2` will result in `[Harry, Potter, Tom]`

Adding `Henry` at `1` will result in `[Harry,Henry,Potter,Tom]`

Adding `Natalie` at `0` will result in `[Natalie, Harry, Henry, Potter, Tom]`

If you want output as `[Natalie,Henry,Tom,Harry,Potter]`

Then you need to replace three `add` operation as

```
    al.add(0, "Tom");
    al.add(0, "Henry");
    al.add(0, "Natalie");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).
Parameters:
index index at which the specified element is to be inserted
element element to be inserted
Throws:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

that means that whenever you enter a a new value at any index where a value already exits then the new value is taken first and the existing value is pushed right.

e.g in your case you entered input as Herry and potter and latter you entered Natalie at 0th index, Herry at 1st index and tom at 2nd index.

so the output shall be 
Natalie
Herry 
Herry
Potter
Tom

for more details please rea the link : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28int%2Cjava.lang.Object%29